# problem in setting parameters for NSMutableURLRequest ( POST request)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, post, http-post

am setting the parameters(key-value pairs - user name, password, email id) for NSMutableURLRequest(POST) using the class method

```
 + (void)setProperty:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key inRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
```

and requesting the server using sendSynchronous.

But at the server end, the parameters are null.

plz suggest me some other new solution???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ASIFormDataRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Its `-setPostValue:forKey:` method makes POSTing data as `application/x-www-urlformencoded` or `multipart/form-data` dead simple.

If you want to use `NSURLRequest` instead, check out [the OAuthConsumer project](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/OAuthConsumer/) for an example of using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Start by reading `-setParameters:` in `NSMutableURLRequest+Parameters.m and go from there. For sending data as`multipart/form-data`using`NSURLRequest`, see Facebook's [FBRequest](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m#L105-165).

`+[NSURLProtocol setProperty:forKey:inRequest:]` is intended to be used to extend the URL loading system to support additional protocols:

> Protocol implementors who need to extend the capabilities of `NSURLRequest` and `NSMutableURLRequest` [by providing categories on these classes] can store and retrieve protocol-specific request data by using `NSURLProtocol`’s class methods `propertyForKey:inRequest:` and `setProperty:forKey:inRequest:`. ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: @yokks Edited with links to examples of using `NSURLRequest`.